# How to include files in code:blocks build?

Tags: c, include, codeblocks

I was wondering how to include files like LUA scripts, dlls, ect in a code:blocks build (debug and release) or would I just have to copy over all the files manually to the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is done by manual organization